# How to recognize numbers in a string using JS?

Tags: javascript

If we have a string, say

```
'1, 2, 3, 4'
'1, 2, 3 GO!'
'ZOMG THE %^*@#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!'
```

then how do I recognize that its has numbers and return true?

I need it because while using,

```
if(input == input.toUpperCase())
```

if a number is entered this condition returns true, so need to add an elegant way to stop the numbers from passing this condition.

Edit1: The string is indeed comma separated, I already have googled ways that recognize non comma separated strings as numbers.

Edit2: Added more examples of what I need to pass.

Comment: `alert('(1, 2, 3, 4)'.search(/\d/) !== -1);`

Comment: Does regex meet your requirements?  What other strings do you need to be able to parse?

Comment: @Brad Regex is my last resort, all alphabets, special characters and umlauts.

Comment: @PrakashWadhwani Why would regex be your last resort if it does exactly what you want?  And, I'm saying that if you want to parse a wide variety of strings, you should provide more than one example in your question.  Otherwise, it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Brad its classical problem called Bob, you can read about it here, http://jsfiddle.net/pzoc03vm/ and the tests that need to be passed are, http://jsfiddle.net/7yzfpor9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3764814) are appropriate for this:

```
var str = "(1, 2, 3, 4)";
var containsNumber = /\d/.test(str);      // true
```

Here, `\d` is a regular expression that will match if your string contains a digit anywhere.

---

Ok, looks like you need to look for lowercase letters... If there's any lowercase letter it shouldn't be considered *yelling*.

```
var str = "(1, 2, 3, 4)";
var containsLowercaseLetters = /[a-z]/.test(str);      // false
```

This will only work for latin letters though. In your case, it may be simpler to just state:

```
var isYelling = (input == input.toUpperCase()) && (input != input.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Ok, although it works with numbers only, but I need to also check if there is an alphabet with them, then it has to fail the test.

Comment: @PrakashWadhwani Update your question with an appropriate test case.

Comment: Updated. Beware of asking [X-Y problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659) in the future ;)

Comment: Aha! Exactly what I was looking for, simple and elegant without any confusing regex, toLowerCase beautifully rejects numbers, I wish I had thought that myself! Thanks Lucas!